# Do android widgets require default activity to launch?

Tags: android, android-widget

I searched a lot for this question and tried everything mentioned on the internet but still couldn't find a solution. My widget gets installed but does not update on clicking. I have not  created a default activity for it.
My problem is that my action on clicking the button is not changing.

Here is my code:
//Android manifest

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.android.pictureapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="7"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <receiver android:name=".MyWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
        <receiver
            android:name="MyWidgetIntentReceiver"
            android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.android.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
                android:resource="@xml/widget_info" />
        </receiver>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

//MyWidgetProvider.java- this class contains the onUpdate method and has listeners.

```
package com.example.android.pictureapp;

import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetManager;
import android.appwidget.AppWidgetProvider;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

import com.example.android.pictureapp.R;

public class MyWidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {


    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,int[] appWidgetIds){

        //Log.i("Tag","In onUpdate method");
        System.out.println("Tag In onUpdate method");
        RemoteViews views=new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button, buildButtonPendingIntent(context));
        Log.i("Tag","Context value after setOnClickPI before pushWIDGET:"+context);

        pushWidgetUpdate(context,views);
        Log.i("Tag","after pushwidget update:"+context);
    }

    public static PendingIntent buildButtonPendingIntent(Context context){

        Intent intent=new Intent();
        intent.setAction("com.example.android.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE");

        Log.i("Tag","intent's action:"+intent);
        return PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
    }

    public static void pushWidgetUpdate(Context context,RemoteViews views){

        System.out.println("Inside pushwidget");
        ComponentName myWidget=new ComponentName(context, MyWidgetProvider.class);
        AppWidgetManager manager=AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context);
        manager.updateAppWidget(myWidget, views);
    }
}
```

//MywidgetIntentReceiver.java - This class contains onReceive method and performs the function to do after clicking.

```
package com.example.android.pictureapp;

import com.example.android.pictureapp.R;

import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.RemoteViews;

public class MyWidgetIntentReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static int clickCount = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        // Log.i("Tag1","In onReceive:"+intent);
        System.out.println("In onReceive()");

        if (intent.getAction().equals(
                "com.example.android.intent.action.CHANGE_PICTURE")) {
            updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(context);
        }
    }

    private void updateWidgetPictureAndButtonListener(Context context) {

        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setImageViewResource(R.id.widget_image, getImageToSet());

        System.out.println("in updateWidgetPicture method");
        // Log.i("Tag","in updaeWIdgetPicture method");
        // remember to set ur button click listeners
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.widget_button,
                MyWidgetProvider.buildButtonPendingIntent(context));

        MyWidgetProvider.pushWidgetUpdate(context.getApplicationContext(),
                views);
    }

    private int getImageToSet() {
        clickCount++;
        Log.i("Tag", "in getImageToSet()" + clickCount);

        return clickCount % 2 == 0 ? R.drawable.paypal_logo : R.drawable.paypaldonation;
    }
}
```

//layout/widget_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:layout_margin="5sp"
    >

    <ImageView 
        android:id="@+id/widget_image"
        android:layout_width="110dp"
        android:layout_height="110dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/paypal_logo"
        />

    <Button 
        android:id="@+id/widget_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:text="Change it"
        />

</LinearLayout>
```

//xml/widget_info.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:minWidth="146dp"
    android:minHeight="146dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="5000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"
    >


</appwidget-provider>
```

//MainACtivity

```
package com.example.android.pictureapp;

import com.example.android.pictureapp.R;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        //getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

And these are the changes to the manifest:

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.android.pictureapp.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

Comment: What version of Android are you on?

Comment: min=7 and max=17 and the device is 4.0.4

Comment: Does your app have another Activity which you can open?

Comment: Also, nothing is coming in my log cat. I have may log statements but no one is shown.

Comment: @RaghavSood. No activity. I didnt create any activity

Comment: @Raghav Sood: Thanks, it worked. I created a new project and did all over again by creating the activity and it worked!!!

Comment: So does that mean widget requires an activity to launch and cannot be done without it???????

Comment: @Athiska yes, on android 3.1 and above you have to launch an activity first

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting Android 3.1, your app must have at least one Activity that the user can launch before it will receive any broadcasts etc.

Since you don't have an Activity, your widget's broadcast probably isn't received because the system thinks your app is in a stopped state. Try adding an Activity.

Comment: Error:"Activity not started. Its current task has been brought to front."

Comment: I am adding the code above for the activity that I have created. The activity is being shown but the widget button still not updating.